# Error while inserting row into SQL Server with identity

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

Let us consider the following connection string which connects to SQL Server using the ODBC  driver:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxx.xx.xx.xx,xxxx;Database=mydata;Uid=xx;Pwd=xxxxxx;
```

- Database type: SQL Server
- Driver: SQL Server - ODBC native client 10.0
- Provider type: `System.Data.Odbc`

I am executing this command:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1.table ON;

INSERT INTO db1.table 
   SELECT * FROM db.table

SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1.table OFF;
```

I am getting errors:

> *ERROR [23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]An
>   explicit value for the identity column in table 'db1.table' can only
>   be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.*

What I have to do now in order to solve the issue?

Waiting for your responses..

Comment: The error message is clear enough. You need to specify each target and source column in the INSERT...SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly list the columns to insert into:

```
INSERT db1.table(IdColumn, Column1, Column2)
SELECT IdColumn, Column1, Column2
FROM db.table
```

You should specify the column names as standard practice anyway to avoid bugs creeping in (e.g. columns misaligned, new columns added etc). When using IDENTITY_INSERT, this is actually enforced by SQL Server, per the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when user has attempted to insert a row containing a specific identity value into a table that contains an identity column. Run following commands according to your SQL Statement:

Before your SQL Statement:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <tablename> ON
```

--You have to make a column list for your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT Into tableA ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5] ) 
SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5] FROM tableB
```

not like:

```
 "INSERT Into tableA SELECT ........"
```

After your SQL Statement :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <tablename> OFF
```